# wordpress export pretty permalinks and post excerpt export

Tags: export

Note: tried all old questions and they seem not working in current version of wp

I want to export pretty permalinks ( not in db) ,posts title,excerpt and if possible category and tags to csv
Please tell me how to

Comment: *What exactly* have you tried so far? Please expand your question by some code, even if semi-functional. As is, this is too broad and hence not answerable. Also you are not asking a question at all, really.

Comment: I tried avaialbe plugin in respostery

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464701/export-list-of-pretty-permalinks-and-post-title not working

Answer (score 0):

In what way are you trying to output them? This is a rough code, but with adaption it'll do what you want it to do- bear in mind though that this is PHP so you will need to make a page template with it, or build it into a shortcode. It cannot be used as-is and is not a packaged plugin:

```
<?php
$exportposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=999'); // get all of them
foreach($exportposts as $exportpost) {
setup_postdata($exportpost);
the_title();
echo " >> ";
the_permalink();
}
?>
```

Will output posts in a

TITLE >> PERMALINK

form.

Comment: Instead of `'posts_per_page=999'` (which will cut it short if you have 1000+ posts), you can use `'posts_per_page=-1'`, which get *all* the posts.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters .

Comment: Hi I created page template ,but something missed check output at http://www.placementmantra.com/all/

Comment: template used was <?php
/*
Template Name: all 
*/

$exportposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=999'); // get all of them
foreach($exportposts as $exportpost) {
setup_postdata($exportpost);
the_title();
echo " >> ";
the_permalink();
}



?>

Answer (score -2):

Consider using an XML sitemap generator. It's quick, easy and complete for all but no index, no follow pages

Comment: Please add details/explanation to back your answer.